# Use Fiddler 2 To Attach A New File

Tags: html, css, httprequest, fiddler, auto-responder

**Question:** Is it possible to attach a new file on the online server using fiddler?
I know the autoresponder feature but it replaces the file i think...

**What I Want**: Let say there is a file on the server http://www.myserver.com/page/index.html and a stylesheet "style.css" is linked to it. Now, what do to if I want to attach a new stylesheet on this live server say "stylesheet_2.css" without replacing "style.css"? So when the page http://www.myserver.com/page/index.html loads on my computer, two stylesheets (style.css and stylesheet_2.css) start working on it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called 'combined.css', put both 'style.css' and 'stylesheet_2.css' in it.

In Fiddler Autoresponser, set a rule to match the 'style.css' and response the 'combined.css'.

Comment: Yes i know i can do it that...So isn't it possible to just attach a new file?

Comment: @Symbolwdd You may need to autoresponse the html and modify the html content.

Comment: How'd I modify the html content using autoresponder?

Comment: Just like how to modify the combined.css file.